# how to develop the same project in github using the different accounts

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

I want to develop a project with mates . The project is in my repository.  If it is possible for my mates to commit their code to my repository directly using their own accounts without my permission and code review? How to realize this? I need some details. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add them as collaborators on the repo (in the Settings tab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [this](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-another-user-s-repository/)? Your mates can propose file changes. Then all you have to do is accept them.

Comment: thanks and I mean if it's possible for mates to push code directly in my repository without my acceptance

Comment: @user1826 Try [this](http://example.com)  then. It allows you to add your friends to the organisation. Don't forget to press the tick button if this worked!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to add multiple ssh keys per account and then add them to your config file.

---

https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996

---

### ***`create different public key`***

create different ssh key according the article Mac Set-Up Git

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@youremail.com"
```

for example, 2 keys created at:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
```

---

### ***`Add these two keys to the ssh-agent:`***

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2
you can delete all cached keys before

$ ssh-add -D
```

---

### ***`check your keys`***

```
$ ssh-add -l
```

---

#### `Add the keys to the config file:`***

```
#activehacker account
Host github.com-1
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1

#jexchan account
Host github.com-2
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_1
```